# How to convert full path of a file to only the file name in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, filenames, filepath

I have a variable called `%file%` and it contains path to a file, i want that ONLY the file name in a new variable called `%file_name%` (without the extension like .exe). I am new to batch scripting so this might be very easy...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use variable expansion to strip the extension.  See the last couple of pages of `help for` for details.  How does `%file%` get set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%i in (%file%) do @echo %%~nxi
```

n for name

x for extension

for more options see `for /?`

Comment: well, try it  ;-)  looks fine.